# vba sort array by string length and alphabetically

Tags: vba, sorting

say after using the `Split` function we have an array of strings like so `ArrStr = ("this","is","a","random","phrase")`

**what I want to achieve is this:**

- first, `ArrStr` is sorted by the string length of the array items, i.e `ArrStr = ("a","is","this","random","phrase")` since len("a") = 1, len("is") = 2 ...etc
- second, `ArrStr` then gets sorted again but this time alphabetically retaining the first sort by length, i.e `ArrStr = ("a","is","this","phrase","random")` ,the string "phrase" took the place of the string "random" since it starts with "p" and we all know that the letter "p" comes before the letter "r" in the English language.

during the sorting process, the text is considered case insensitive

**any *efficient* ideas on how to achieve that?**

Answer (score 3):

Any sort algorithm will work - all you need to do is make your item comparisons based on your custom criteria:

```
Private Function SortCompare(one As String, two As String) As Boolean
    Select Case True
        Case Len(one) < Len(two)
            SortCompare = True
        Case Len(one) > Len(two)
            SortCompare = False
        Case Len(one) = Len(two)
            SortCompare = LCase$(one) < LCase$(two)
    End Select
End Function
```

For example, with a quicksort:

```
Public Sub CustomQuickSort(list() As String, first As Long, last As Long)
    Dim pivot As String
    Dim low As Long
    Dim high As Long

    low = first
    high = last
    pivot = list((first + last) \ 2)

    Do While low <= high
        Do While low < last And SortCompare(list(low), pivot)
            low = low + 1
        Loop
        Do While high > first And SortCompare(pivot, list(high))
            high = high - 1
        Loop
        If low <= high Then
            Dim swap As String
            swap = list(low)
            list(low) = list(high)
            list(high) = swap
            low = low + 1
            high = high - 1
        End If
    Loop

    If (first < high) Then CustomQuickSort list, first, high
    If (low < last) Then CustomQuickSort list, low, last
End Sub
```

Usage example:

```
Public Sub SampleCode()
    Dim sample() As String
    sample = Split("this,is,a,random,phrase", ",")
    CustomQuickSort sample, LBound(sample), UBound(sample)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(sample) To UBound(sample)
        Debug.Print sample(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you want this to sort descending, swap the `SortCompare = True` and `SortCompare = False` lines.

Comment: This algorithm was just what I needed.  I had to add parenthesis in the ```pivot``` calculation so the addition happened before the division.  I submitted an edit to the code.